# filetype os.walk search speeding up the code

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a function that traverses a directory tree searching for files of a designated filetype which works just fine the only problem I have is it can be quite slow. Can anyone offer more pythonic suggestions to potentially speed the process up:

```
def findbyfiletype (filetype, directory):
"""

    findbyfiletype allows the user to search by two parameters, filetype and directory.

    Example:
        If the user wishes to locate all pdf files with a directory including subdirectories
        then the function would be called as follows:

        findbyfiletype(".pdf", "D:\\\\")

        this will return a dictionary of strings where the filename is the key and the file path is the value
        e.g.
            {'file.pdf':'c:\\folder\\file.pdf'}


        note that both parameters filetype and directory must be enclosed in string double or single quotes
        and the directory parameter must use the backslash escape \\\\  as opposed to \ as python will throw a string literal error
"""

indexlist =[]                       #holds all files in the given directory including sub folders
FiletypeFilenameList =[]            #holds list of all filenames of defined filetype in indexlist
FiletypePathList = []               #holds path names to indvidual files of defined filetype

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        indexlist.append(os.path.join(root,name))
        if filetype in name[-5:]:
            FiletypeFilenameList.append(name)

for files in indexlist:
    if filetype in files[-5:]:
        FiletypePathList.append(files)

FileDictionary=dict(zip(FiletypeFilenameList, FiletypePathList))
del indexlist, FiletypePathList, FiletypeFilenameList

return FileDictionary
```

ok so this is what I ended up with using a combintion of @Ulrich Eckhardt @Anton and @Cox

```
import os
import scandir

def findbyfiletype (filetype, directory):
    FileDictionary={}

    for root, dirs, files in scandir.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            if filetype in name and name.endswith(filetype):
                FileDictionary.update({name:os.path.join(root,name)})

return FileDictionary
```

as you can see it's been re factored getting rid of the unnecessary lists and creating the dictionary in one step. @Anton your suggestion for the scandir module helped greatly reduced the time in one instance by about 97 percent which nearly blew my mind.

I'm Listing @Anton as the accpeted answer as it sums up all that i actually acheived with refactoring but @Ulrich Eckhardt and @Cox both get up votes as you were both very helpful

regards

Comment: One obvious issue here is that you are building a list and then iterating that list to build a dict. If you used a generator expression, this would avoid the memory overhead of the list and could possibly even exploit the background directory-readahead (IO-bound) that is now interleaved with handling the data (CPU-bound). That said, what if `foo/file.pdf` and `bar/file.pdf` exist? Lastly, the `filetype in name[-5:]` only works in very limited cases.

Comment: This is a rough draft of a function so bear with me. In the event of duplicates there would be an md5 check on the files. But the purpose was to locate all files of a given filetype regardless of duplicates. Also filetype in name [-5:] will be edited to endswith.

Comment: I'm just saying that the returned info can not possibly capture the case that you have two files that have the same name but in different directories, regardless of their contents.

Comment: More pythonic:
* you are searching for file extensions, not file types - so name accordingly
* ease user input, demanding "pdf" and "D" only [`findbyextension("pdf", "D")`], and expand the necessary dot and slashes in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `os.walk()`, you can use the faster [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) module ([PEP-471](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)).

Also, a few other tips:

- Don't use the arbitrary `[-5:]`. Use the `ensdswith()` string method or use `os.path.splitext()`.
- Don't build up two long lists and then make a dict. Build the dict directly.
- If escaping back slashes bother you, use forward slashes like 'c:/folder/file.pdf'. They just work.

Answer (score 1):

walk() can be slow because try to cover a lot of things.
I use a simple variant:

```
def walk(self, path):
    try:
        l = (os.path.join(path, x) for x in os.listdir(path))
        for x in l:
            if os.path.isdir(x):self.walk(x)
            elif x.endswith(("jpg", "png", "jpeg")):
                self.lf.append(x)
    except PermissionError:pass
```

That's fast and python do a local cache of filesystem, so a second invocation is even faster.

PS: function walk is member of a class, obviously, that's why „self” is there.

EDIT: in NTFS, don't bother with islink. Update with try/except.

But this just ignore dirs where you don't have permissions. You have to run script as admin if you want them listed.

Comment: a member of what class?

Comment: it makes perfect sense that this would be faster and it is but I've just tried this on several test systems and it seems that the code appears to not be  agnostic in that on some systems it will throw an error because it doesn't have permissions to access certain folders. The original code doesn't worry about permissions. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: May be from separator.Edited with os.path.join. If doesn't work, tell us please the filesystem used. You may put a try/except to ignore files/folders where you don't have appropiate permision, but if it is a symlink, it is a different story. It is posible to check with os.path.islink and follow the link

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Of one that you write. The point is not to use the function in global scope, but in a class that keep track of path, list of files/folders and so on.

Comment: As @RobertLear noted, it crashes when os.listdir() throws an exception, which os.walk() by default ignores.

Comment: still throws the permissions error the file systems are ntfs also ran the islink to check if there were symlinks of which there were none